# With this discord bot i've been working on and theres an error i need help fixing (javascript)

Tags: discord.js

When I put my code into VSC and run it with `npm install discord.js` and then `node .`, it literally becomes stuck onto this (see the image). I don't see anything wrong with the code, so I'm confused. I swapped out the phrases, the channel id, and the token so you don't see it.

[image]

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Client } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client({ intents: [32767] })
const prefix = "!"


const channel = client.channels.cache.get('channel id here'); 
    const phrases = [
"phrases here"
];
  setInterval(() => {
  
    channel.send(phrases[Math.floor(Math.random() * phrases.length)]);
  }, 10800000); // Send message every 3 hours (in milliseconds)


  

client.login("token here");
```

Answer (score 0):

To see if the bot has actually logged in use the `ready` event.

```
client.once('ready', () => {
console.log("Logged In")
})
```

This will tell you once the bot has logged in.